# Best way data communication between Mobile android (Client) and Enterprise system (Server)

Tags: android, web-services

I have an question about data communication between Mobile (Client) and Enterprise system (Server)

We have raw data on Enterprise System , Then CMS server will getting data from Enterprise system and manage content to use for presentation, Then Android will load the data from CMS server and display to user. So there are transaction occur from android and I want to push all transaction on android back into Enterprise System.

I can do by sending all transaction back to CMS server ,Then CMS server will send transaction back to enterprise system

OR

I should send all transaction from android directly to enterprise system.

Which is the best way?

**Way 1**

[image]

**Way 2**

[image]

**Note:** Enterprise System may be SAP software, Client may be android and CMS may be .NET or PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can use web service for send data to PHP back end and store it in your database or your enterprise database directly in android. There is login functionally for server and android system. so you are follow same as for send your android data to server . follow this link [login using server]

[Android pass and receive parameter from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042190/android-pass-and-receive-parameter-from-php/13042420#13042420)

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the less hops, the better.  Try to communicate as directly as possible.  I recommend using the  SAP Gateway Server.  If this is / can be available to you, then check out the  [SAP OData Mobile SDK for Android](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/downloads?rid=/webcontent/uuid/b09d414f-f227-2f10-bdbf-ba31c844b432).

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, I would write a web api to handle the requests because of the many unknowns and disjointed systems.

Things to consider

What type of security of security do the systems implement? 
Does the user have access to one, all, or none of the systems? 
Is there a common login for all systems or many levels of security the user will have to enter?
How to handle a user if their access is revoked.
How to handle a user if permissions are revoked for certain functional areas of each system.

It is definitely worth looking into if it is possible to account for the security risks and if it is worth the hassle of programming it.